# pandas subplot, split into rows

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot

how can i make these pie charts appear in say rows of 4 pie charts, instead of one single row?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame( {'vitamin B-2 (mg) Riboflavin': {'Broccoli Chinese': 0.15700000000000003, 'chia seeds': float('nan'), 'raspberries, raw': 0.0, 'coconut milk, canned': 0.0, 'vegemite': 0.602, 'elderberries, raw': 0.03, 'cranberries, raw': 0.0, 'bread wheat, toasted': 0.2, 'egg, omelet': 0.68, 'olive oil, extra virgin': float('nan'), 'sunflower seeds': 0.12, 'butter, salted': 0.0, 'flax seeds': 0.04000000000000001, 'blackberries, raw': 0.0, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 0.375, 'blueberries, raw': 0.0}, 'vitamin D (mg)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 0.0, 'chia seeds': float('nan'), 'raspberries, raw': float('nan'), 'coconut milk, canned': float('nan'), 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': float('nan'), 'cranberries, raw': float('nan'), 'bread wheat, toasted': float('nan'), 'egg, omelet': float('nan'), 'olive oil, extra virgin': float('nan'), 'sunflower seeds': float('nan'), 'butter, salted': 10.08, 'flax seeds': float('nan'), 'blackberries, raw': float('nan'), 'mushroom oyster, raw': float('nan'), 'blueberries, raw': float('nan')}, 'Total Fat (g)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 1.099, 'chia seeds': 6.16, 'raspberries, raw': 0.21, 'coconut milk, canned': 53.25, 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': 0.15, 'cranberries, raw': 0.03, 'bread wheat, toasted': 2.0, 'egg, omelet': 20.4, 'olive oil, extra virgin': 8.0, 'sunflower seeds': 15.45, 'butter, salted': 14.597999999999999, 'flax seeds': 8.440000000000001, 'blackberries, raw': 0.15, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 0.5, 'blueberries, raw': 0.111}, 'Vitamin A (IU)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 2571.6600000000003, 'chia seeds': float('nan'), 'raspberries, raw': 9.9, 'coconut milk, canned': 0.0, 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': 180.0, 'cranberries, raw': 18.0, 'bread wheat, toasted': 0.0, 'egg, omelet': 972.4, 'olive oil, extra virgin': 0.0, 'sunflower seeds': 15.0, 'butter, salted': 449.82, 'flax seeds': 0.0, 'blackberries, raw': 64.2, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 60.0, 'blueberries, raw': 19.98}, 'Cholestrol (mg)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 0.0, 'chia seeds': 0.0, 'raspberries, raw': 0.0, 'coconut milk, canned': float('nan'), 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': 0.0, 'cranberries, raw': 0.0, 'bread wheat, toasted': 0.0, 'egg, omelet': 605.1999999999999, 'olive oil, extra virgin': float('nan'), 'sunflower seeds': 0.0, 'butter, salted': 38.699999999999996, 'flax seeds': 0.0, 'blackberries, raw': float('nan'), 'mushroom oyster, raw': 0.0, 'blueberries, raw': 0.0}, 'Phosphorus (mg)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 64.37, 'chia seeds': 189.60000000000002, 'raspberries, raw': 8.7, 'coconut milk, canned': 240.0, 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': 11.7, 'cranberries, raw': 3.9, 'bread wheat, toasted': 90.2, 'egg, omelet': 275.4, 'olive oil, extra virgin': float('nan'), 'sunflower seeds': 198.0, 'butter, salted': 4.32, 'flax seeds': 128.4, 'blackberries, raw': 6.6, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 150.0, 'blueberries, raw': 4.4399999999999995}, 'Vitamin B-6 (mg)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 0.15700000000000003, 'chia seeds': float('nan'), 'raspberries, raw': 0.03, 'coconut milk, canned': float('nan'), 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': 0.06, 'cranberries, raw': 0.03, 'bread wheat, toasted': 0.0, 'egg, omelet': 0.17, 'olive oil, extra virgin': float('nan'), 'sunflower seeds': 0.39, 'butter, salted': 0.0, 'flax seeds': 0.1, 'blackberries, raw': 0.0, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 0.125, 'blueberries, raw': 0.037}, 'linoleic acid (g)': {'Broccoli Chinese': float('nan'), 'chia seeds': float('nan'), 'raspberries, raw': float('nan'), 'coconut milk, canned': float('nan'), 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': float('nan'), 'cranberries, raw': float('nan'), 'bread wheat, toasted': float('nan'), 'egg, omelet': float('nan'), 'olive oil, extra virgin': float('nan'), 'sunflower seeds': float('nan'), 'butter, salted': float('nan'), 'flax seeds': 1.1800000000000002, 'blackberries, raw': float('nan'), 'mushroom oyster, raw': float('nan'), 'blueberries, raw': float('nan')}, 'Zinc (mg)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 0.6280000000000001, 'chia seeds': 0.7000000000000001, 'raspberries, raw': 0.12, 'coconut milk, canned': 1.5, 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': 0.03, 'cranberries, raw': 0.03, 'bread wheat, toasted': 0.8, 'egg, omelet': 1.53, 'olive oil, extra virgin': float('nan'), 'sunflower seeds': 1.5, 'butter, salted': 0.018, 'flax seeds': 0.86, 'blackberries, raw': 0.15, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 1.0, 'blueberries, raw': 0.074}, 'Dietry Fiber (g)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 3.9250000000000003, 'chia seeds': 7.540000000000001, 'raspberries, raw': 1.95, 'coconut milk, canned': float('nan'), 'vegemite': 0.546, 'elderberries, raw': 2.1, 'cranberries, raw': 1.38, 'bread wheat, toasted': 2.2, 'egg, omelet': 0.0, 'olive oil, extra virgin': float('nan'), 'sunflower seeds': 2.5799999999999996, 'butter, salted': 0.0, 'flax seeds': 5.460000000000001, 'blackberries, raw': 1.5899999999999999, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 2.875, 'blueberries, raw': float('nan')}, 'vitamin E (mg)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 0.785, 'chia seeds': float('nan'), 'raspberries, raw': 0.27, 'coconut milk, canned': float('nan'), 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': float('nan'), 'cranberries, raw': 0.36, 'bread wheat, toasted': 0.2, 'egg, omelet': 2.04, 'olive oil, extra virgin': 2.096, 'sunflower seeds': 9.96, 'butter, salted': 0.414, 'flax seeds': 0.06, 'blackberries, raw': 0.36, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 0.0, 'blueberries, raw': 0.222}, 'Monosaturated (g)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 0.15700000000000003, 'chia seeds': 0.42000000000000004, 'raspberries, raw': 0.03, 'coconut milk, canned': 2.25, 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': 0.03, 'cranberries, raw': 0.0, 'bread wheat, toasted': 0.4, 'egg, omelet': 8.5, 'olive oil, extra virgin': 5.76, 'sunflower seeds': 5.55, 'butter, salted': 3.78, 'flax seeds': 1.5, 'blackberries, raw': 0.0, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 0.0, 'blueberries, raw': 0.0}, 'vitamin B-1 (mg) Thiamin': {'Broccoli Chinese': 0.15700000000000003, 'chia seeds': float('nan'), 'raspberries, raw': 0.0, 'coconut milk, canned': 0.0, 'vegemite': 0.77, 'elderberries, raw': 0.03, 'cranberries, raw': 0.0, 'bread wheat, toasted': 0.2, 'egg, omelet': 0.17, 'olive oil, extra virgin': float('nan'), 'sunflower seeds': 0.44999999999999996, 'butter, salted': 0.0, 'flax seeds': 0.32000000000000006, 'blackberries, raw': 0.0, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 0.125, 'blueberries, raw': 0.0}, 'vitamin B-5 (mg) Pantothenic acid ': {'Broccoli Chinese': 0.31400000000000006, 'chia seeds': float('nan'), 'raspberries, raw': 0.09, 'coconut milk, canned': 0.5, 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': 0.03, 'cranberries, raw': 0.09, 'bread wheat, toasted': 0.2, 'egg, omelet': 2.04, 'olive oil, extra virgin': float('nan'), 'sunflower seeds': 0.33, 'butter, salted': 0.018, 'flax seeds': 0.2, 'blackberries, raw': 0.09, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 1.625, 'blueberries, raw': 0.037}, 'Total Carbs (g)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 5.966, 'chia seeds': 8.76, 'raspberries, raw': 3.57, 'coconut milk, canned': 7.0, 'vegemite': 1.393, 'elderberries, raw': 5.52, 'cranberries, raw': 3.6599999999999997, 'bread wheat, toasted': 26.8, 'egg, omelet': 1.19, 'olive oil, extra virgin': float('nan'), 'sunflower seeds': 6.0, 'butter, salted': 0.018, 'flax seeds': 5.78, 'blackberries, raw': 3.0599999999999996, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 8.125, 'blueberries, raw': float('nan')}, 'Starch (g)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 0.0, 'chia seeds': float('nan'), 'raspberries, raw': 0.0, 'coconut milk, canned': float('nan'), 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': float('nan'), 'cranberries, raw': 0.0, 'bread wheat, toasted': float('nan'), 'egg, omelet': 0.0, 'olive oil, extra virgin': float('nan'), 'sunflower seeds': float('nan'), 'butter, salted': 0.0, 'flax seeds': 0.0, 'blackberries, raw': 0.0, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 0.0, 'blueberries, raw': float('nan')}, 'Omega-3 fatty acids (mg)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 405.06, 'chia seeds': 3510.4, 'raspberries, raw': 37.8, 'coconut milk, canned': float('nan'), 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': 25.5, 'cranberries, raw': 6.6, 'bread wheat, toasted': 77.2, 'egg, omelet': 261.8, 'olive oil, extra virgin': 0.10800000000000001, 'sunflower seeds': 22.2, 'butter, salted': 56.699999999999996, 'flax seeds': 4562.6, 'blackberries, raw': 28.2, 'mushroom oyster, raw': float('nan'), 'blueberries, raw': 21.46}, 'Calcium (mg)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 157.0, 'chia seeds': 126.2, 'raspberries, raw': 7.5, 'coconut milk, canned': 45.0, 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': 11.4, 'cranberries, raw': 2.4, 'bread wheat, toasted': 79.2, 'egg, omelet': 79.89999999999999, 'olive oil, extra virgin': 0.08, 'sunflower seeds': 23.4, 'butter, salted': 4.32, 'flax seeds': 51.0, 'blackberries, raw': 8.7, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 3.75, 'blueberries, raw': 2.2199999999999998}, 'Trans (g)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 0.0, 'chia seeds': float('nan'), 'raspberries, raw': float('nan'), 'coconut milk, canned': float('nan'), 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': float('nan'), 'cranberries, raw': float('nan'), 'bread wheat, toasted': float('nan'), 'egg, omelet': 1.19, 'olive oil, extra virgin': float('nan'), 'sunflower seeds': float('nan'), 'butter, salted': float('nan'), 'flax seeds': float('nan'), 'blackberries, raw': float('nan'), 'mushroom oyster, raw': float('nan'), 'blueberries, raw': float('nan')}, 'Choline (mg)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 39.721000000000004, 'chia seeds': float('nan'), 'raspberries, raw': 3.69, 'coconut milk, canned': 21.25, 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': float('nan'), 'cranberries, raw': 1.65, 'bread wheat, toasted': 10.6, 'egg, omelet': 360.4, 'olive oil, extra virgin': 0.0432, 'sunflower seeds': 16.53, 'butter, salted': 3.384, 'flax seeds': 15.740000000000002, 'blackberries, raw': 2.55, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 60.875, 'blueberries, raw': 2.2199999999999998}, 'Protein (g)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 1.7270000000000003, 'chia seeds': 3.12, 'raspberries, raw': 0.36, 'coconut milk, canned': float('nan'), 'vegemite': 1.778, 'elderberries, raw': 0.21, 'cranberries, raw': 0.12, 'bread wheat, toasted': 6.2, 'egg, omelet': 18.02, 'olive oil, extra virgin': float('nan'), 'sunflower seeds': 6.24, 'butter, salted': float('nan'), 'flax seeds': 3.66, 'blackberries, raw': 0.42, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 4.125, 'blueberries, raw': 0.259}, 'Betaine (mg)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 0.15700000000000003, 'chia seeds': float('nan'), 'raspberries, raw': 0.24, 'coconut milk, canned': 0.0, 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': float('nan'), 'cranberries, raw': 0.06, 'bread wheat, toasted': float('nan'), 'egg, omelet': 0.85, 'olive oil, extra virgin': float('nan'), 'sunflower seeds': 10.62, 'butter, salted': 0.054, 'flax seeds': 0.6200000000000001, 'blackberries, raw': 0.09, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 15.125, 'blueberries, raw': 0.074}, 'Vitamin C (mg)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 44.274, 'chia seeds': float('nan'), 'raspberries, raw': 7.859999999999999, 'coconut milk, canned': 2.5, 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': 10.799999999999999, 'cranberries, raw': 3.99, 'bread wheat, toasted': 0.0, 'egg, omelet': 0.0, 'olive oil, extra virgin': 0.0, 'sunflower seeds': 0.42, 'butter, salted': 0.0, 'flax seeds': 0.12, 'blackberries, raw': 6.3, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 0.0, 'blueberries, raw': 3.5889999999999995}, 'Saturated Fat (g)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 0.15700000000000003, 'chia seeds': 0.6400000000000001, 'raspberries, raw': 0.0, 'coconut milk, canned': 47.25, 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': 0.0, 'cranberries, raw': 0.0, 'bread wheat, toasted': 0.4, 'egg, omelet': 5.609999999999999, 'olive oil, extra virgin': 1.104, 'sunflower seeds': 1.3499999999999999, 'butter, salted': 9.251999999999999, 'flax seeds': 0.7400000000000001, 'blackberries, raw': 0.0, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 0.0, 'blueberries, raw': 0.0}, 'vitamin K (mcg)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 133.136, 'chia seeds': float('nan'), 'raspberries, raw': 2.34, 'coconut milk, canned': float('nan'), 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': float('nan'), 'cranberries, raw': 1.5299999999999998, 'bread wheat, toasted': 2.8, 'egg, omelet': 7.6499999999999995, 'olive oil, extra virgin': 8.72, 'sunflower seeds': 0.0, 'butter, salted': 1.26, 'flax seeds': 0.86, 'blackberries, raw': 5.94, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 0.0, 'blueberries, raw': 7.141}, 'Polyunsaturated (g)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 0.471, 'chia seeds': 4.66, 'raspberries, raw': 0.12, 'coconut milk, canned': 0.5, 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': 0.06, 'cranberries, raw': 0.03, 'bread wheat, toasted': 0.8, 'egg, omelet': 3.9099999999999997, 'olive oil, extra virgin': 0.84, 'sunflower seeds': 6.930000000000001, 'butter, salted': 0.54, 'flax seeds': 5.74, 'blackberries, raw': 0.09, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 0.0, 'blueberries, raw': 0.037}, 'Potassium (mg)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 409.77000000000004, 'chia seeds': 32.0, 'raspberries, raw': 45.3, 'coconut milk, canned': 550.0, 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': 84.0, 'cranberries, raw': float('nan'), 'bread wheat, toasted': 107.0, 'egg, omelet': 193.79999999999998, 'olive oil, extra virgin': 0.08, 'sunflower seeds': 193.5, 'butter, salted': 4.32, 'flax seeds': 162.60000000000002, 'blackberries, raw': 48.6, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 525.0, 'blueberries, raw': 28.49}, 'Folate (mcg)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 155.43, 'chia seeds': float('nan'), 'raspberries, raw': float('nan'), 'coconut milk, canned': 35.0, 'vegemite': 140.0, 'elderberries, raw': 1.7999999999999998, 'cranberries, raw': 0.3, 'bread wheat, toasted': 41.2, 'egg, omelet': 66.3, 'olive oil, extra virgin': float('nan'), 'sunflower seeds': 68.1, 'butter, salted': 0.54, 'flax seeds': 17.400000000000002, 'blackberries, raw': 7.5, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 33.75, 'blueberries, raw': 2.2199999999999998}, 'Manganese (mg)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 0.471, 'chia seeds': 0.44000000000000006, 'raspberries, raw': 0.21, 'coconut milk, canned': 2.0, 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': float('nan'), 'cranberries, raw': 0.12, 'bread wheat, toasted': 0.6, 'egg, omelet': 0.0, 'olive oil, extra virgin': float('nan'), 'sunflower seeds': 0.57, 'butter, salted': 0.0, 'flax seeds': 0.5, 'blackberries, raw': 0.18, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 0.125, 'blueberries, raw': 0.111}, 'Vitamin B-12 (mcg)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 0.0, 'chia seeds': float('nan'), 'raspberries, raw': float('nan'), 'coconut milk, canned': 0.0, 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': 0.0, 'cranberries, raw': 0.0, 'bread wheat, toasted': 0.0, 'egg, omelet': 1.87, 'olive oil, extra virgin': float('nan'), 'sunflower seeds': 0.0, 'butter, salted': 0.036, 'flax seeds': 0.0, 'blackberries, raw': 0.0, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 0.0, 'blueberries, raw': 0.0}, 'Omega-6 fatty acids (mg)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 119.32000000000001, 'chia seeds': 1157.0, 'raspberries, raw': 74.7, 'coconut milk, canned': 582.5, 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': 48.6, 'cranberries, raw': 9.9, 'bread wheat, toasted': 748.0, 'egg, omelet': 3360.9, 'olive oil, extra virgin': 1.4240000000000002, 'sunflower seeds': 6914.4, 'butter, salted': 491.03999999999996, 'flax seeds': 1182.2, 'blackberries, raw': 55.8, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 50.0, 'blueberries, raw': 32.56}, 'Sodium (mg)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 10.99, 'chia seeds': 3.8000000000000003, 'raspberries, raw': 0.3, 'coconut milk, canned': 32.5, 'vegemite': 241.50000000000003, 'elderberries, raw': 1.7999999999999998, 'cranberries, raw': 0.6, 'bread wheat, toasted': 294.0, 'egg, omelet': 273.7, 'olive oil, extra virgin': 0.16, 'sunflower seeds': 2.6999999999999997, 'butter, salted': 103.67999999999999, 'flax seeds': 6.0, 'blackberries, raw': 0.3, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 22.5, 'blueberries, raw': 0.37}, 'Selenium (mcg)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 2.0410000000000004, 'chia seeds': float('nan'), 'raspberries, raw': 0.06, 'coconut milk, canned': float('nan'), 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': 0.18, 'cranberries, raw': 0.03, 'bread wheat, toasted': 16.0, 'egg, omelet': 45.39, 'olive oil, extra virgin': float('nan'), 'sunflower seeds': 15.899999999999999, 'butter, salted': 0.18, 'flax seeds': 5.08, 'blackberries, raw': 0.12, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 3.25, 'blueberries, raw': 0.037}, 'calories': {'Broccoli Chinese': 34.54, 'chia seeds': 98.0, 'raspberries, raw': 15.6, 'coconut milk, canned': 492.5, 'vegemite': 55.86000000000001, 'elderberries, raw': 21.9, 'cranberries, raw': 13.799999999999999, 'bread wheat, toasted': 150.2, 'egg, omelet': 266.9, 'olive oil, extra virgin': 70.72, 'sunflower seeds': 175.2, 'butter, salted': 129.06, 'flax seeds': 106.80000000000001, 'blackberries, raw': 12.9, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 53.75, 'blueberries, raw': 21.09}, 'vitamin B-3 (mg) Niacin': {'Broccoli Chinese': 0.6280000000000001, 'chia seeds': float('nan'), 'raspberries, raw': 0.18, 'coconut milk, canned': 1.5, 'vegemite': 3.5000000000000004, 'elderberries, raw': 0.15, 'cranberries, raw': 0.03, 'bread wheat, toasted': 3.0, 'egg, omelet': 0.17, 'olive oil, extra virgin': float('nan'), 'sunflower seeds': 2.49, 'butter, salted': 0.0, 'flax seeds': 0.6200000000000001, 'blackberries, raw': 0.18, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 6.25, 'blueberries, raw': 0.148}, 'Sugars (g)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 1.2560000000000002, 'chia seeds': float('nan'), 'raspberries, raw': 1.32, 'coconut milk, canned': float('nan'), 'vegemite': 0.15400000000000003, 'elderberries, raw': float('nan'), 'cranberries, raw': 1.2, 'bread wheat, toasted': 3.0, 'egg, omelet': 1.19, 'olive oil, extra virgin': float('nan'), 'sunflower seeds': 0.78, 'butter, salted': 0.018, 'flax seeds': 0.30000000000000004, 'blackberries, raw': 1.47, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 1.375, 'blueberries, raw': float('nan')}, 'Iron (mg)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 0.942, 'chia seeds': float('nan'), 'raspberries, raw': 0.21, 'coconut milk, canned': 8.25, 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': 0.48, 'cranberries, raw': 0.09, 'bread wheat, toasted': 2.0, 'egg, omelet': 2.55, 'olive oil, extra virgin': 0.0432, 'sunflower seeds': 1.56, 'butter, salted': 0.0, 'flax seeds': 1.1400000000000001, 'blackberries, raw': 0.18, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 1.625, 'blueberries, raw': 0.111}, 'Magnesium (mg)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 28.26, 'chia seeds': float('nan'), 'raspberries, raw': 6.6, 'coconut milk, canned': 115.0, 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': 1.5, 'cranberries, raw': 1.7999999999999998, 'bread wheat, toasted': 28.4, 'egg, omelet': 17.0, 'olive oil, extra virgin': float('nan'), 'sunflower seeds': 97.5, 'butter, salted': 0.36, 'flax seeds': 78.4, 'blackberries, raw': 6.0, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 22.5, 'blueberries, raw': 2.2199999999999998}, 'Vitamin B-7 (mg) Biotin': {'Broccoli Chinese': float('nan'), 'chia seeds': float('nan'), 'raspberries, raw': float('nan'), 'coconut milk, canned': float('nan'), 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': float('nan'), 'cranberries, raw': float('nan'), 'bread wheat, toasted': float('nan'), 'egg, omelet': float('nan'), 'olive oil, extra virgin': float('nan'), 'sunflower seeds': float('nan'), 'butter, salted': float('nan'), 'flax seeds': 0.0, 'blackberries, raw': float('nan'), 'mushroom oyster, raw': float('nan'), 'blueberries, raw': float('nan')}, 'Copper (mg)': {'Broccoli Chinese': 0.15700000000000003, 'chia seeds': 0.04000000000000001, 'raspberries, raw': 0.03, 'coconut milk, canned': 0.5, 'vegemite': float('nan'), 'elderberries, raw': 0.03, 'cranberries, raw': 0.03, 'bread wheat, toasted': 0.0, 'egg, omelet': 0.17, 'olive oil, extra virgin': float('nan'), 'sunflower seeds': 0.54, 'butter, salted': 0.0, 'flax seeds': 0.24, 'blackberries, raw': 0.06, 'mushroom oyster, raw': 0.25, 'blueberries, raw': 0.037}} )

plot = df.plot.pie(subplots=True, figsize=(20, 30), legend=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `df.plot.pie(subplots=True, layout=(4,10), legend=False)`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thats amazing, thanks, one more questions how to get rid of the text and just show one legend as the legend is the same for all of them, so showing one legend would suffice for all pie charts

Comment: The legends are all different, depending on which categories are shown in the respective pie. In case you have one pie where *all* categories are present, you could use that legend and remove all other. Else you will need to recreate from scratch.